# A certain ideal of a valuation ring

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

This is a question from Frohlich and Taylor's book 'Algebraic Number Theory', page 60.

Let $\mathfrak o$ be a Dedekind domain with quotient field $K$ and let $v$ be a discrete valuation on $K$. Let $\mathfrak o_v$ be the valuation ring of $v$ in $K$ and $\mathcal P_v$ be the valuation ideal of $v$ in $K$. Assume that $\mathfrak o \subset o_v$ and set $\mathfrak p_v=\mathcal P_v\cap\mathfrak o$.

Is it possible that the $\mathfrak o_v$-ideal $\mathfrak p_v\mathfrak o_v$ equals $\mathfrak o_v$?

Answer (score 1):

Certainly not—we have $1\in \mathfrak{o}_\nu$ but $1\notin \mathcal{P}_\nu$.

In fancier but perhaps more intuitive language: $\mathfrak{o}_\nu$ is the localization of $\mathfrak{o}$ with respect to $\mathfrak{p}_\nu$, i.e. $\mathfrak{o}_\nu$ is always a local ring, and $\mathfrak{p}_\nu \mathfrak{o}_\nu$ is always its maximal ideal.

Comment: I was wondering if a finite sum $\sum_i x_iy_i$ where $x_i\in \mathfrak p_v$ and $y_i\in \mathfrak o_v$ could equal $1$.

Comment: Such a sum still lives in the ideal $\mathcal{P}_\nu$, regardless of what trickery is going on downstairs.